# Get request fails on SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, smartcard, restsharp

I'm creating C#/.NET application which requires to
validate the certificate on the smartcard.

Basically in Chrome/Firefox the user store the card to the smartcard slot/device, then the certification is stored to computer and then in browser the window for entering pin is showed(specific url).

I'm creating the application which used login based on this. When loging in I should GET 200 response from that specific url after entering pin correctly(this window for pin is not from my application and it is open when client.Execute from restsharp is called).

My code looks like this

```
        // We need to allow other security protocol types
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                                               SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        // WSE 3.0 methods
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        string findValue = "MyCompany";
        X509Certificate2Collection certsCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, findValue, false);

        var client = new RestClient("https://blablabla.test.com");
        client.ClientCertificates = certsCollection;
        var request = new RestRequest("ssltest3/", Method.GET);

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        return true
```

**As you can see I am using currently RestSharp for GET request. When I enter pin correctly on the first time then everything goes well. But when I enter first bad pin and after this correct I get response with "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."**

We check the apache and when entering pin there are some empty GET request on background.

I tried also trick for setting ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback to true but this doesn't work.

That mycrosoft cryptoapi is strange but I don't want to use pkc11.

Any idea to not get "Could not ...."?
I spend a lot of time on this.....

Comment: Surely instead of true - you need to return if the login was successful, if it wasnt, get a new pin number and try again?

Comment: But how? I don't think that this is solution because method set to ServerCertificateValidationCallback is not called after entering the correct or incorrect PIN through microsoft cryptoapi.